# How do I delete DB rows for a range of partial keys?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a SQLite database table defined with 3 primary keys: Foo, Bar, and Charlie.

I also have a list of partial keys -- pairs of Foo, Bar.

I would like to delete all rows in the database table that match the partial key. I understand and intend that the partial key can match multiple rows, and want each partial match deleted in that case.

If I was using a list of *just* a single key, I could do something to the effect of:

```
"Delete from TABLENAME where FOO IN ('" + String.Join("','", fooList) + "')";
```

If I was using a **single** value *and* a partial key, I could do something to the effect of:

```
"Delete from TABLENAME where FOO = <foo_value> AND BAR = <bar_value>";
```

Is there some way to combine the `IN` syntax with a **list** of multiple partial-key entries?

Comment: Do youhave this list of Foos and Bars in variables or in another database table?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger Variables; A C# List<fooBarKey>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use the IN syntax with multiple columns

```
 Delete from TABLENAME 
  where (FOO = <foo_value1> AND BAR = <bar_value1>)
     or (FOO = <foo_value2> AND BAR = <bar_value2>);
```

Comment: Well, I don't *need* to use `IN`, just looking for a way to handle the deletion in a similar way -- and this looks like it'll do exactly what I'm after!

Comment: If that is the answer you can indicate with a check

Comment: Well aware, just needed to wait out the timer. Thanks!